# android app gets updated via internet

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I want to make an android application.i.e.It's a quiz application.
Like after publishing my app I added some new question.
I want when user get connected to internet application should be updated.

So how can I update application from internet?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the data held in sqlite within the app? If so, you could look for updates to data on the internet (presumably on a website you already host) everytime the app starts. Do this in an async task so that it doesn't affect the user experience.

If newer data is found, you could fetch it and update the sqlite tables in the background.

Answer (score 0):

- Data bundled with app : If you compile and upload a new apk file to play store, update will show in users play store. This is good for occasional updates, like a new version of app or so.
- Data not bundled with app : you can make your app fetch its  question data from a remote server. This is easier for very frequent updates, like you add questions daily on a web site. But you will need a server.